# Google Credentials, Photos API

Tags: android

Estou tentando fazer uma integração de um APP com o Google Photos. Seguindo o Get Started é possível ver o seguinte código:

```
// Set up the Photos Library Client that interacts with the API
PhotosLibrarySettings settings =
 PhotosLibrarySettings.newBuilder()
.setCredentialsProvider(
    FixedCredentialsProvider.create(/* Add credentials here. */)) 
.build();

try (PhotosLibraryClient photosLibraryClient =
    PhotosLibraryClient.initialize(settings)) {

    // Create a new Album  with at title
    Album createdAlbum = photosLibraryClient.createAlbum("My Album");

    // Get some properties from the album, such as its ID and product URL
    String id = album.getId();
    String url = album.getProductUrl();

} catch (ApiException e) {
    // Error during album creation
}
```

Notem que para se criar um objeto photosLibraryClient é preciso configurar um cliente. No exemplo apenas possui um comentário dizendo para inserir as credenciais. Indo no GitHub da google onde é possivel encontrar alguns exemplos, encontrei uma classe que gera o photosLibraryClient baseado em escopos que estão definidos na classe e mais um endereço de arquivo. Pelas minhas pesquisas este arquivo é um JSON de configuração da aplicação feita no Google Web Console, onde se registra a utilização das APIs.

```
/** Creates a new {@link PhotosLibraryClient} instance with credentials and scopes. */
public static PhotosLibraryClient createClient(
        InputStream inputStream, List<String> selectedScopes)
        throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    PhotosLibrarySettings settings =
            PhotosLibrarySettings.newBuilder()
                    .setCredentialsProvider(
                            FixedCredentialsProvider.create(
                                    getUserCredentials(inputStream, selectedScopes)
                            )).build();
    return PhotosLibraryClient.initialize(settings);
}

private static Credentials getUserCredentials(InputStream inputStream,   List<String> selectedScopes)
        throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets =
            GoogleClientSecrets.load(
                    JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    String clientId = clientSecrets.getDetails().getClientId();
    String clientSecret = clientSecrets.getDetails().getClientSecret();

    GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow =
            new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                    GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport(),
                    JSON_FACTORY,
                    clientSecrets,
                    selectedScopes)
                    //.setDataStoreFactory(new FileDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_DIR))
                    .setAccessType("offline")
                    .build();
    LocalServerReceiver receiver =
            new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(LOCAL_RECEIVER_PORT).build();
    Credential credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, receiver).authorize("user");
    return UserCredentials.newBuilder()
            .setClientId(clientId)
            .setClientSecret(clientSecret)
            .setRefreshToken(credential.getRefreshToken())
            .build();
}
```

O problema é que ao ler o arquivo um erro de IllegalArguments é apresentado na seguinte linha:

```
String clientId = clientSecrets.getDetails().getClientId();
```

Alguém já fez uma autenticação no photos e pode me ajudar? Não estou utilizando a APIREST do photos pois não entendo as configurações necessárias para habilitar o serviço

Comment: você já fez uma conta antes no https://developers.google.com/? você geralmente gera credentiais lá pras apis.

Comment: Sim, tenho conta e a aplicação já possui acesso as APIs, incluindo a Photos. A credencial é para uma aplicação android, ao qual me deu um chave que salvei, e um JSON com o nome da aplicação e mais um monte de caracteres. Também criei um cliente com acesso a API que me deu outro JSON chamado clientSecret. Edit: Tentei carregar outro arquivo, agora o clientsecret e obtive um erro chamado "java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: JKS KeyStore not available". A linha indicada do erro é posterior ao do post que havia dado a primeira exceção, sendo ela " GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport()"